# In nodejs code getting no-loops/no-loops eslint error for using for and for-of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, eslint

In my nodejs application I am using for and for-of loops but es-lint is giving linting error as  **error  loops are not allowed  no-loops/no-loops**.Below is the code I am using.

```
for(const item of arrObj){
    await model.update({id:item.id},{$set:{value:item.value}});
}
```

Can someone help to know which looping is best option in order to perform database operation inside loop.

Comment: Uh, don't use that eslint rule if you want to use loops?

Comment: actually we required to use eslint rules as per our requirement

Comment: Then you should ask the person who made this a requirement. It just makes no sense. A  `for … of` loop is the most straightforward, simple and idiomatic way to run a sequence of asynchronous side effects.

Comment: maybe use GOTO instead of a loop?</irony off>